# Get a field from a ListView

Tags: android, custom-adapter

I have an Activity with ListView took in my Database. I would like to, when I select one, get the id field.

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessageConversationView);
    Cursor c = selectInfoInDB();
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.idMessageClavier, R.id.nomMessageClavier, R.id.valeurMessageClavier, R.id.groupeMessageClavier, R.id.occurrenceMessageClavier};

    SimpleCursorAdapter sCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.conversation_clavier_display_data, c, SmartAccess_v1Activity.nomColonnesMessage, to);
    lv.setAdapter(sCA);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idMessageClavier);                
        }
    });
```

The fields in the ListViews are correct, but the toast give me the id of the first item of ListView, wherever I touch on list.

I worked on that and i I can't figure where is the mistake -_-

Thanks for your help, korax

Comment: This findView... Is called on activity not row view ... Use view.find... But still its .. Stupid  .... You should consider to use adapterview.getitemsmthin(dont have doc now) and - since youre using cursor adapter - you will get cursor that points row you need ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int postion,
                    long id) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "id is :: " + id +"position :: " + position,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```